# Scheme two lists intersection

Tags: functional-programming, scheme

I've written this code

```
(define (in-list? val ls)
  (if (null? ls) #f 
    (if 
        (= (car ls) val) #t
        (in-list? val (cdr ls))
    )
  )
)
(define (intersect ls1 ls2)
  (if (null? ls1)
    '()
    (if (in-list? (car ls1) ls2) 
        (cons (car ls1) (intersect (cdr ls1) ls2))
        (intersect (cdr ls1) ls2)
    )
  )
)
```

It works correctly if I ask (intersect '(1 2 3) '(1 4 7)) but it returns empty list when I try (intersect '(a b c) '(a b d))

Comment: That is because `=` only works for numerical values. Try `eq?` instead.

Comment: Thanks I then solved problem with `equal?`. `eq?` works as well

Comment: @Iraklius `eq?` won't work for values that are too large to be stored as a pointer or at all in a Scheme that doesn't store values in pointers. eg. `(eq? "test" "test")` is undefined and both `#t` and `#f` are acceptable result. Always use `equal?` when you don't know what types you can get and want value comparison.

Comment: I didn't know that. Thank you

Comment: what should the output be for `(intersect '(1 2 3 1 2 3 4) '(1 2 4 4))` ?

Comment: The result will be `(1 2 1 2 4)` it was supposed to duplicate values